# How to relate a percentage to another percentage, ordering the result in a range between 0 and 1, and using weights

Tags: percentage

EDIT: I am referring to yearly return from trading is the first time series, the second one is an index the SPX

---

I have some yearly measurements M1 : 2021 ->3%;  2020 ->14% ; 2019 ->-15%

I could calculate a simple average and determine the mean 1% and then compare how every year the percentage differs by the average.

But I have a really strong correlated series M2:  2021 -> 15%; 2020 ->10%; 2019 ->-4%

I want to model M1 taking into account M2, so that for instance the M1 result 2019 -15% is "normalised" to the fact that that year 2019 was 4%

Ideally would like to "normalise"/"model" every year  with a scale between 0.00 and 1.00 so that can compare how significant is the M1 result `compared` to M2, as bonus would like to weight the result of M2 according to some parameters, for instance if -5% then weight with a coefficient of 1.3 if is less(for ex. -18% or -8%) 1.55

I do not expect that you spend time solving this, is just I am really really frustrated, that do not know which statistic/ math tool I should use to solve this kind of problems, so would like to know which key words or which subject should study to solve a problem like that(that in my case is a financial problem, I even posted in the quant forum, but thought that here could get more theoretic support to understand which topic should study because is a math data analysis problem first of all)

Comment: Please tell us what this percentages represent in real life!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yearly return from trading is the first time series, the second one is an index the SPX

Comment: Please add this new information to the post as an edit